# sudo ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64 ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib64/lib': File exists

Tags: symbolic-link

I try to install Davinci Resolve 14.0 on my Ubuntu 17.04, when I enter command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64
```

then shows:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib64/lib': File exists
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64` tries to create a symbolic link `lib` inside of `/usr/lib64` but there already is a `lib` directory inside `/usr/lib64` so it can't create the symbolic link.

You should probably try to create the symbolic link of specific libraries that you want from `/usr/lib` inside `/usr/lib64`.

For example:
If you want `libm.so` to be found inside `/usr/lib64`do

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libm.so /usr/lib64/lib
```